# Given a bounded arithmetic sequence and a divisor, find the most common quotient.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I have the following problem in number theory:

I have a **bounded** natural arithmetic sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in [0, N]}$ given by $a_k = a_0 + kb$ for $k \in [0, N]$. I also have a divisor $d$.

I need a quotient $q$, such that $q$ is the most common element in the sequence $\{\lfloor \frac{a_n}{d} \rfloor\}_{n \in [0, N]}$.

For example, if I have $a_0 = 8, b = 5, N = 6, d = 12$, then the sequence $a_n$ has the $7$ elements $8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38$. The quotients when divided by $d$ are, respectively, $0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3$. So I am interested in finding $q = 1$, because that is the mode.

I needed to solve the same problem for the most common remainder, but that was easy, simply take the remainder of $a_0$, because if a remainder repeats, then the remainder of the first element in an arithmetic sequence will repeat first. But the quotients are harder.

I could try using Euclid's algorithm to find $x, y$, such that $xb + yd = gcd(b, d)$, then try to find the element with the least remainder and take its quotient, but that may not work, because the sequence is bounded. For example, here, $gcd(5, 12) = 1$, so the least achievable remainder in an unbounded sequence would be $0$, at $a_8 = 48$. I would then take $q = \frac{a_8}{d} = 4$, but that is wrong, because $a_8$ is not even a valid element of the sequence. We can only go up to $a_6 = 38$.

Thanks!

Comment: is there good reason to imagine that there is a simple way to get this?  A priori, it's a function of $4$ variables, right?  I suggest:  fix three of them, vary the other.  See if there is a recognizable pattern.  If there is, you can try to generalize it.

Comment: Suppose you divide the elements of the sequence into blocks with the same quotient. You can discard the first and last blocks by considering them separately. This leaves the blocks in between which we can be sure are "full". I believe this then turns into a Chinese Remainder Theorem for two moduli. We expect a single remainder mod $b$, but a (contiguous) range of remainders mod $q$ which would land us sufficiently close to the beginning of a block. The solution to this system of congruences would be another bounded arithmetic sequence, from which we'd take the least element.

Comment: So... maybe it's doable, if we can solve a system of congruences with one target being a contiguous range, to obtain the least result or an arithmetic sequence of results. I'd wager that this is either possible, or equivalent to breaking RSA.